# using threads to delete files with specific extensions ignoring files over a certain date

Tags: multithreading, powershell

In my profession I make forensic images from "foreign" PCs which I extract later on my local storage.

To clean up the data I'd hope to delete all files that aren't relevant for me. (not limited to: audio, movies, systemfiles,...)
Since we're speaking of multiple TB of data, I'd have hoped to use threads, especially since my storage is all flash and the limitation on the disk is somewhat less of a problem.

To speed the process up after an initial manual run, I would want the script to exclude files older then 1 day (since I have done that one already with a manual run).

what I have so far:

```cs
$IncludeFiles = "*.log", "*.sys", "*.avi", "*.mpg", "*.mkv", ".mp3", "*.mp4",
                "*.mpeg", "*.mov", "*.dll", "*.mof", "*.mui", "*.zvv", "*.wma",
                "*.wav", "*.MPA", "*.MID", "*.M4A", "*.AIF", "*.IFF", "*.M3U",
                "*.3G2", "*.3GP", "*.ASF", "*.FLV", "*.M4V", "*.RM", "*.SWF",
                "*.VOB"
$ScriptBlock = {
    Param($mypath = "D:\")
    Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -Recurse -File -Include $file | Where-Object {
        $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
    }
    foreach ($file in $IncludeFiles) {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $file
    }
    Get-Job | Wait-Job 
    $out = Get-Job | Receive-Job 
    Write-Host $out
```

the only thing that doesn't work is the limitation that it only looks at files "younger" than 1 day. If I run the script without it, it seems to work perfectly. (as it gives me a list of files with the extensions I want to remove)

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. The scriptblock is never closed, and `$file` is undefined. Also, putting a command in a scriptblock and starting it a s a job is not going to speed up anything. You need to break up the command in a way that will allow you to run time-consuming operations as several jobs in parallel.

Comment: i wanted to use every extention as a different thread, seeing as it will search through all the data for 1 extension, then move on to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter passing doesn't work the way you seem to expect. `Param($mypath = "D:\")` defines a parameter `mypath` with a default value of `D:\`. That default value is superseded by the value you pass into the scriptblock via `-ArgumentList`. Also the variable `$file` inside the scriptblock and the variable `$file` outside the scriptblock are not the same. Because of that an invocation

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList '*.log'
```

will run the command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '*.log' -Recurse -File -Include $null | ...
```

Change your code to something like this to make it work:

```cs
$ScriptBlock = {
    Param($extension)
    $mypath = "D:\"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $mypath -Recurse -File -Filter $extension | Where-Object {
        $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
    }
}

foreach ($file in $IncludeFiles) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $file
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Using `-Filter` should provide [better performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow/) than `-Include`, but accepts only a single string (not a list of strings like `-Include`), so you can only filter one extension at a time.